# AOP: Check if method returned exception or not with an After advice

Tags: aop, aspectj

I know that I can use an `@AfterReturning` or `@AfterThrowing` advice in order to check if a method returned a result or an exception, but what if I wanted to use the `@After` advice?

Is there a way to check if the method returned something or an exception using the `@After` advice?

Comment: No, you can't do that. You shall use `@AfterReturning` or `@AfterThrowing` for those purposes.

Answer (score 0):

`@After` it's advice that applied for the normal case or case with exception without separation.

`@AfterReturning` - in case method completed without exceptions.

`@AfterThrowing` - in case when method completed with the exception.

In you need to know about method completion you can do it with @Around advice.

```
 @Around("pointcut")
 public Object execute(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable {          
    try {                  
         Object result = pjp.proceed(); 
         //here you know that method is completed without exception  
         return result;
    }
    catch(Throwable ... Exception ..... ex) {
        //here you know that method throws exception
        log() , wrap() , handle()..... whatever....
    }
 }
```